# Browser isn't clearing cookie when logging out on server, but does clear cookie for localhost

Tags: node.js, cookies, auth0

I'm writing a node-js server using express, with auth0 for log-in support. When I run my server in a local docker container, navigating to /logout correctly clears my browser's cookie (tested on both safari and chrome.)

But when I visit "/logout" on the server, the cookie doesn't appear to be cleared properly, and visiting "/" shows a main page, not a login form.

The NodeJS code for "/logout":

```
router.get("/logout", (request, response) => {
    if (request.session) {
        request.session.destroy(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    request.logout();
    response.clearCookie("id_token");
    response.clearCookie("connect.sid");
    response.redirect("/");
});
```

The NodeJS code to check if the user is logged in, for all requests:

```
router.get("/*", (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    passport.authenticate("jwt", {
        session: false,
    }, (error, isAuthenticated, _) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error)
        }

        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            const origin = encodeURIComponent(request.originalUrl || ""); 
            return response.redirect(`/login?origin=${origin}`);
        }
        next();
    })(request, response, next);
});
```

When I click log out on my local docker version, in the network tab I see the following requests:

Logout:

[image: Cookies, after logging out, localhost]

[image: Log out network request, localhost]

Redirect to /: (works correctly on localhost)

[image: Cookies still cleared on localhost]

[image: Loading main page shows a redirect to Auth0 login view]

As you can see, the cookie is cleared, and when I visit /, I get an Auth0 login page.

When this PR is deployed to our test server, clicking the logout button appears to clear the cookies properly, but when redirecting to / the main page shows anyways, without a login prompt. It appears that the id_token cookie isn't cleared properly.

[image: Cookies after logging out on server]

[image: log out network, on server]

After "logging out", the browser redirects to / like it should, but instead of seeing a login page, it shows the main page, with the user still logged in. Here's the cookies and network tab for loading / after logging out on the server:

[image: cookies when visiting / on server]

[image: network tab, visiting / on server after logging out]

What differences between localhost and the server could cause chrome to not clear the cookie properly?

Comment: Is the domain for /logout path is the same as for /?

Comment: Yes. For the server, the URL for logging out is `localhost:8080/logout` while on the server it is `mycompany.com/logout`. When viewing the main page, the URLs are `localhost:8080/` and `mycompany.com/`

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? Try setting explicit `/` path to the cookie when you set it. I can see that the cookie that is set has `N/A` as path and the cookie that is deleted has `/` path.

Comment: The problem occurs in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. I'm running Mac OS X Mojave.